# How to keep an Activity running while screen off?

Tags: android

How to keep an Activity running/active when the screen shuts off?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to use a [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) to ensure that your activity is kept active. `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` must be requested in your manifest. However, battery will drain faster, so do remember to **release** the wakelock as soon as possible.

Alternately, use a **[Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)** instead

Answer (score 3):

In the onCreate of your Activity, put the following lines:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock =  powerManager.newWakeLock(PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"motionDetection:keepAwake");
wakeLock.acquire();

//Place this where you no longer need to have the processor running
wakeLock.release();
```

After you press the power button, the activity should still run if that's where you closed it.

If you were like me, and you were collecting accelerometer data, be sure to remove the default `sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);` from the onPause part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a good way.
I found this some months ago and it save a little bit the battery life ;)

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you don't have ' android:noHistory="true" ' in your manifest file for any of the activities. It kills the activity when the app goes off the screen or screen shuts off.

If you want your app stay active even if the screen is off I don't think you need to do anything extra: My application doesn't have any extra code for it and when I turn the screen off and on it is still there. But! Android OS probably kills it after a while when the screen is off, so you should probably use WAKE_LOCK in your manifest file. Or you can add ' android:keepScreenOn="true" ' to the manifest file to keep the screen ON all the time when your app is running.